# Is there a jquery selector extractor akin to the xpather firefox extension?

Tags: jquery, xpath

Firefox has an [Xpather](http://xpath.alephzarro.com/) extension that allows one to inspect html and extract xpaths. Is there something similar to extract jQuery selectors from html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Selector Gadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen one but there are 101 ways to use css selectors and it is not too tough...not worth a tool imo.